# Yii framework: dropDownList onchange not working

Tags: yii2

I have resource regarding dropDownList onchange event, but when I select my dropdownlist that is nothing happen and dint show any error message.

This is my **dropdownlist** in **view**:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'pro_id')
     ->dropDownList($pro_option,         // options
     ['prompt'=>'...'] , // options
     ['onchange' => '$.post("'.Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(["transaction/price"]).'"+$(this).val(), function( data ) {
         $("#transactionform-r_price").html( data );
     })']);?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'r_price')->textInput(['readonly' => true]) ?>
```

This is my controller(TransactionController.php) **actionPrice**:

```
public function actionPrice($id)
{
    $price = 123;
    return $price;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please correct your syntax like this.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'pro_id')->dropDownList($pro_option, [
    'prompt' => '---Select Value---',
    'onchange'=>'$.get( "'.Url::toRoute(['transaction/price']).'", { id : $(this).val() })
        .done(function(data) {
            $( "#'.Html::getInputId($model, 'r_price').'").html(data);
    });'
]) ?>
```

Comment: Hi, my url is show like `http://localhost/basic/web/index.php?r=transaction%2Fprice%269` i got a error msg 404 (Not Found)

Comment: @ReiTee. please try updated last options in my updated answer

Comment: @ReiTee. use get method because you are pass `$id` in controller action

Comment: add top of page `use yii\helpers\Url;`

Comment: Thank!! Its work! But write javascript on dropdownlist ,its a good idea?

Comment: If you call only action its good but write many line code is not good.